# How to reset my C# program (Windows mobile)?

Tags: c#, windows-mobile

How I can reset my C# program ?

I want that my program will start again

in Windows mobile

thank's in advance

Answer (score 1):

> One way is to P/Invoke (or use an
>   existing wrapper) around the 
>   CeRunAppAtTime API, schedule your app
>   to launch in a couple of seconds time,
>   and exit. The SDF
>   (www.opennetcf.org/sdf/) has a wrapper
>   for this API.
>
> Peter
>
> --  Peter Foot  Device Application Development MVP  www.peterfoot.net |
>   www.inthehand.com

From The Internet Archive ( http://web.archive.org/web/20071231144636/http://www.themssforum.com/Compact/application-restart/ ). (I gave up on figuring out why the url parser hates that link)

See [CeRunAppAtTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms913957.aspx) on MSDN.

Unlike Zanoni's solution, this will not have two instances of your application running at the same time.  It's much uglier, though.

Answer (score 0):

Run:

```
ProcessStartInfo s = new ProcessStartInfo();
s.FileName = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase;
s.UseShellExecute = false;
Process.Start(s);
```

And:

```
Application.Exit();
```

Answer (score -1):

There is the [Application.Restart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.restart.aspx) method, but it doesn't look like it's supported on the Compact Framework.  You could try:

```
Application.Exit();
Application.Run(new MyForm());
```

Comment: Application.Exit() will result in a exit 0 code to the application... 
Application.Run(new MyForm()) doesn't work after...

Comment: Please reread to documentation... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157894.aspx  "This method does not necessarily force the application to exit."